# How to set value in the gin context for testing

Tags: go, go-gin

I have a handler function that looks like this:

```
func Foo(service bar.Service) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
         // some code
         userId, exists := c.Get("user_id")
         if !exists {
            // log error
            return
         }
         c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{})
    }
}
```

I have a middleware function in handler that authenticates some headers and sets the user_id value in the gin context. In my unit test, I want to only call the `Foo` handler without calling that middleware function which sets the `user_id` value. In the test, I want to assert on response code for the function so I am using `"net/http/httptest"` library's ResponseRecorder. So far the test looks like this but I am not sure about how to set the value in the context that ResponseRecorder will be using. Below test is not working and it's not getting the user_id value from the context.

```
gin.SetMode(gin.TestMode)
w := httptest.NewRecorder()
c, engine := gin.CreateTestContext(w)
c.Set("user_id", "abc")
config := testutil.HTTPRecorderParams{
        Method:  "POST",
        Path:    "/foo",
        Handler: endpoints.Foo(mockService),
        Body:    "{\"bar\": \"baz\"}",
    }
engine.Handle(config.Method, config.Path, config.Handler)
jsonStr := []byte(config.Body)

req, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(context.Background(), config.Method, config.Path, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))

engine.ServeHTTP(w, req)

assert.Equal(t, w.Code, http.StatusOK)
```